# Intercambio de datos entre vistas y subvistas en Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, blade

Tengo una vista que recibe una variable llamada `$estado`. Lo he comprobado y la recibe perfectamente desde el controlador.

A continuación incluyo una subvista

```
@include('calculo')
```

La ruta es correcta. Ambas están directamente en `resources/views/`

La subvista `calculo.blade.php` tiene un código tal que en base al valor de `$estado` calcula una variable `$resultado`

El problema es que `$resultado` no me aparece en la vista principal. Cuando intento usarla, me salta una excepción porque dice que no está.

Si el código de `calculo.blade.php` lo meto en la vista principal si me reconoce la variable `$resultado`.

La documentación de laravel dice que ***All variables that are available to the parent view will be made available to the included view***, por lo que entiendo que la subvista recibe `$estado`. En cambio no dice nada de que las variables de la subvista estén disponibles en la vista principal.

Hay algún modo de sacar las variables de la subvista a la vista principal?

Gracias a todos.

Comment: Creo que lo que intentas hacer no es posible de la forma en la cual lo estás haciendo. Podrías utilizar el helper `session(['key' => 'value']);` en la subvista y `session()->get('key');` en la principal.

Comment: Te lo agradezco. Así, si funciona. El problema con el helper `session` es que cuando lo usas en una vista para asignar valores (no para leerlos) es que debe ir entre `@php` y `@endphp`. Si no, aparece como texto en la vista, y no se ejecuta. Esto ni siquiera está en la documentación oficial de Laravel. Pero salvando eso, tu idea me ha venido genial. Gracias

Comment: Tienes la opción de pasarle parámetros a la 'subvista' @include('calculo', ['estado' => $estado, 'otroValor'=>$otroValor])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La documentación de *Laravel* (y otras aplicaciones) no contempla muchas situaciones que podemos llegar a "probar", muchas de las cuales no funcionan o acaban generando errores.

Como has dicho, la documentación de Laravel indica que ***las variables disponibles en una vista estarán también disponibles para las vistas incluidas en esta*** (vistas hijas), pero no se indica que ocurre a la inversa, es decir si la vista que incluye a otra puede acceder a las variables de esta vista que es incluida.

#### Ejemplo:

Tenemos un template "padre.blade.php" y otro "hijo.blade.php" en el directorio "resources/views/" y para la prueba definimos la ruta:

```
Route::get('padre', function () {
    return view('padre');
});
```

El contenido de *padre* será:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head></head>
<body>
    @php
        $testPadre = 'Padre';
    @endphp
    @include('hijo')

    <p>Template padre / Contenido de $testPadre: {{ $testPadre }}</p>
    <p>Template padre / Contenido de $testHijo: {{ $testHijo }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

El contenido de *hijo* será:

```
@php
    $testHijo = 'Hijo';
@endphp

<p>Template hijo / Contenido de $testPadre: {{ $testPadre }}</p>
<p>Template hijo / Contenido de $testHijo: {{ $testHijo }}</p>
```

Si tratamos de cargar esta vista, en *Laravel 5.7*, salta la siguiente excepción:

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: testHijo (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\desarrollos\milaravel\resources\views\padre.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\desarrollos\milaravel\resources\views\padre.blade.php)
```

y a la derecha se indica que el error se produce en la línea:

```
<p>Template padre / Contenido de $testHijo: <?php echo e($testHijo); ?></p>
```

es decir, que `$testHijo` no es visible en el template *padre*. ***Con esto se reproduce tu problema.***

Podemos, evitar la excepción seteando la variable `$testHijo` en el template padre, antes de intentar usarlo:

```
@php
    $testPadre = 'Padre';
    $testHijo  = '';
@endphp
```

Ahora la vista cargaría correctamente mostrando:

```
Template hijo / Contenido de $testPadre: Padre
Template hijo / Contenido de $testHijo: Hijo
Template padre / Contenido de $testPadre: Padre
Template padre / Contenido de $testHijo:
```

pero al usar `$testHijo` en el template padre, aunque la página funciona, seguimos sin tener acceso al valor que le damos en el template *hijo*, ***Blade simplemente no está diseñado para que funcione de esta manera***. Para hacer esto se requiere usar un pequeño "hack".

**Cuando necesitas pasar un dato entre diferentes partes de una aplicación desarrollada en PHP la solución más sencilla pasa por usar el almacenamiento en sesión.** Cómo estamos trabajando en *Blade* y *Laravel*, usaremos el helper `session()`.

Para guardar un valor en la sesión, dentro de *Laravel / Blade*, lo hacemos de la siguiente forma:

```
@php
    session(['session-key' => 'the-value']);
@endphp
```

Siguiendo con nuestro ejemplo de prueba, en el template hijo ponemos:

```
@php
    $testHijo = 'Hijo';
    session(['dato-desde-el-hijo' => $testHijo]);
@endphp
```

Ahora, cambiamos el template padre para que recupere de la sesión el dato que hemos cargado en el template hijo (si lo encuentra):

```
@php
    $testPadre = 'Padre';
    $testHijo  = (session('dato-desde-el-hijo'))
        ? session()->get('dato-desde-el-hijo') : '';
@endphp
```

Si volvemos a cargar la página tendremos exactamente el mismo resultado que en el caso anterior:

```
Template hijo / Contenido de $testPadre: Padre
Template hijo / Contenido de $testHijo: Hijo
Template padre / Contenido de $testPadre: Padre
Template padre / Contenido de $testHijo:
```

***Repasando...***

Hemos guardado un valor en sesión en el template hijo para usarlo en el padre, aunque NO estamos observando cambios, ¿por qué?

Si te fijas en el código actual, el template hijo se incluye en el padre después del bloque `@php` donde se trata de recuperar el valor de la sesión, es decir, tratamos de recuperarlo antes de almacenarlo en la sesión, luego no existe. *Tendremos que recuperar el dato de la sesión debajo del include.*

***Conclusión...***

**Podemos pasar un dato de un template hijo al padre para usarlo en este, usando el almacenamiento en sesión, pero sólo podremos usarlo en el template padre, después del punto en el que incluimos el template hijo en el que lo almacenamos.**

Entonces el código quedaría así para el template padre:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head></head>
<body>
    @php
        // limpiar datos de sesión para evitar falsos resultados al
        // repetir las pruebas
        session()->flush();

        // declarar las variables en el padre
        $testPadre = 'Padre';
        $testHijo  = '';
        /* $testHijo  = (session('dato-desde-el-hijo'))
            ? session()->get('dato-desde-el-hijo') : ''; /* HACK: */
    @endphp
    @include('hijo')

    <p>Template padre / Contenido de $testPadre: {{ $testPadre }}</p>
    <p>Template padre / Contenido de $testHijo: {{ $testHijo }}</p>

    @php
        $testHijo  = (session('dato-desde-el-hijo'))
            ? session()->get('dato-desde-el-hijo') : ''; /* HACK: */
    @endphp
    <p>Template padre / Contenido de $testPadre: {{ $testPadre }}</p>
    <p>Template padre / Contenido de $testHijo: {{ $testHijo }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

y para el template hijo:

```
@php
    $testHijo = 'Hijo';
    session(['dato-desde-el-hijo' => $testHijo]);
@endphp

<p>Template hijo / Contenido de $testPadre: {{ $testPadre }}</p>
<p>Template hijo / Contenido de $testHijo: {{ $testHijo }}</p>
```

y el navegador mostraría el siguiente resultado:

```
Template hijo / Contenido de $testPadre: Padre
Template hijo / Contenido de $testHijo: Hijo
Template padre / Contenido de $testPadre: Padre
Template padre / Contenido de $testHijo:
Template padre / Contenido de $testPadre: Padre
Template padre / Contenido de $testHijo: Hijo
```